# Emploi et conjugaison de l'expression « ça va aller »

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, conjugaison

Quand peut-on utiliser l'expression **ça va aller** ? Peut-on la conjuguer ? Par exemple **ç'ira aller** s'emploie-t-il ?

Comment: En Belgique, on peut même employer l'expression "[Ca va d'aller](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q2-A22d4EUM)" mais ne cherchons pas de règle grammaticale là derrière... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On va faire simple : Tu peux considérer *ça va aller* avec ou sans interrogation comme une *locution figée* => à utiliser de façon rigoureusement invariable pour exprimer ce que l'on appelle un **futur prochain.**

- Quelqu'un devant toi donne des signes de faiblesse, de difficultés, tu t'inquiètes pour lui et lui demande si *ça va aller*. (s'il pense que sa situation peut s'améliorer rapidement)
- Quelqu'un s'inquiète relativement à son avenir immédiat, sa santé ou sa réussite dans un projet en cours, tu le rassures en lui affirmant *ça va aller!" (Il connaîtra très bientôt une issue favorable à ses problèmes / soucis)

À la condition de ne pas t'arrêter là, en ajoutant un comparatif par exemple, ( *Ça va aller mieux*) un adjectif (*ça va aller mal*) tu peux vouloir le conjuguer : (***Tu vas*** aller mieux, **les choses vont aller** de mal en pis...) MAIS ATTENTION, le premier verbe aller (celui utilisé en tant qu'authentique auxiliaire) **ne peut se conjuguer qu'au présent de l'indicatif.**

Cela dit en première réponse rapide.
Si on veut rentrer dans le détail, le futur prochain est un truc... compliqué, j'y reviendrai si tu le souhaites mais... plus tard.

Comment: Merci. Je connais le futur proche. Tu parle de lui quand tu dis futur prochain ? Je pensais que ça va aller est une locution figée mais je ne pensais pas que l'on ne peut pas la conjuguer. Je songé à Venir de qui peut se conjuguer (je viens de manger ; je venais de manger).

Comment: @dimitris : Futur prochain est le terme utilisé dans les livres de référence (genre Grevisse). ATTENTION Il ne se conjugue QUE avec le verbe **aller** comme auxiliaire. Si tu utilises **venir** comme auxiliaire alors on ne parle plus du tout de *futur prochain* mais bien au contraire de *passé récent*. Alors ne compare pas. Au même titre que tous les temps composés (passé composé : auxiliaire conjugué exclusivement au présent / plus que parfait : auxiliaire conjugué exclusivement à l'imparfait, le futur proche ne conjugue l'auxiliaire qu'à un seul temps : le présent.

Comment: Aller peut, en tant qu'auxiliaire se trouver conjugué à l'imparfait. Mais ce n'est là encore plus non plus du futur prochain puisqu'on parle dans ce cas, selon les grammairiens de **conditionnel proche** ou de **futur inéluctable**.

Comment: Comme je le reconnais ci-contre, c'est très compliqué toute cette histoire. Et forcément puisque ces modes sont d'authentiques gallicismes.

Comment: Quel est le problème avec *Tu allais aller mieux* ? Les choses ne sont quand même pas aussi exclusives que tu le laisses penser. Dans des cas normaux l’auxiliaire est conjugué à un temps simple quelconque. Dans des cas comme le futur proche ou le passé récent il y a une restriction supplémentaire d'aspect mais ça laisse quand même la possibilité du présent et de l'imparfait.

Comment: Ah j'avais raté le dernier commentaire.